# D3 - Linestring crossing the map when 2 dots are too far from each other

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have an issue with d3 map + LineString, when Im drawing a line between 2 dots which are far from each other, the generated line is going from one side of the map to the other, is there any way to force LineString to go only to one direction and not to cross the map even if its the shortest path?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56409480/7106086), the geotransform in the first snippet will still project your data but will result in paths treating points as Cartesian rather than points on a globe.